# Learning Java - Making a simple guessing game

Tags: java, loops, logic

I've been trying to learn Java on my own for about a week, and I've decided to try and apply my (pretty limited) knowledge to making a simple guessing game.

Basically the user inputs a number between 1 and 10, and they get feedback depending on whether they guessed too high, too low, or correctly guessed a random number.

My problem is that once I run my method, I don't know how to allow for multiple guesses. Basically they guess once, and then that's it. Game over.

I'm sure it's something simple like a loop I need to implement, maybe an additional variable gets declared if they guess wrong? I don't know.

Can anyone help me out?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creates a new scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // randomly generates a number from 1-10
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int myNumber = rand.nextInt(10)+1; 


    String tooWarm = "Too high. Try again!";
    String tooCold = "Too cold. Try again!";
    String bingo = "Yup! Good guess!";
    boolean playing = true;

    System.out.printf("What's your name? ");
    String name = input.nextLine();     
    System.out.println("Well, " + name + ", betcha can't guess what number I'm thinking of! \nHint: it's between 1 and 10...");
    int value = input.nextInt();


        if (value > myNumber) {
            System.out.println(tooWarm);
        }

        else if (value < myNumber) {
            System.out.println(tooCold);
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(bingo);
        }           

}
}
```

Comment: you need a loop like : ´while(!input.equals("stop"))´

Answer (score 1):

just do this,

do..while makes your execution to execute atleast once.

```
do {

        System.out.println("Enter : ");
        int value = input.nextInt();

        if (value > myNumber) {
            System.out.println(tooWarm);
        }

        else if (value < myNumber) {
            System.out.println(tooCold);
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(bingo);
            playing = false;
        }
    }
    while (playing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of your code:

```
...
char yN = input.nextChar();
if (yN == 'y' || yN == 'Y') {
  main(null);
  return;
  }
}//end of main().
```

basically what it does is that it makes recursive calls, so that the game can be played again and again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creates a new scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // randomly generates a number from 1-10
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int myNumber = rand.nextInt(10)+1; 


    String tooWarm = "Too high. Try again!";
    String tooCold = "Too cold. Try again!";
    String bingo = "Yup! Good guess!";
    boolean playing = true;

    System.out.printf("What's your name? ");
    String name = input.nextLine();     
    System.out.println("Well, " + name + ", betcha can't guess what number I'm thinking of! \nHint: it's between 1 and 10...");
    while(true){
        int value = input.nextInt();


        if (value > myNumber) {
            System.out.println(tooWarm);
        }

        else if (value < myNumber) {
            System.out.println(tooCold);
        }

        else {
            System.out.println(bingo);
            return;
        }           

    }
}
```